# Regex match if a substring is NOT found

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex match only when the substring 'password' is *not* contained in the string.

The only solution that I have come across that claims to solve this is:
`((?!password).)`

however this matched 'password123'

Is this possible with regex? I have a feeling I might have to fall back on coding the logic.

EDIT: I am using Javascripts `pattern.test(string)`

Comment: What regex engine are you using? .net? javascript?

Comment: I am using javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: you need to anchor the regex, and maybe add a quantifier...

```
^((?!password).)+$
```

The `$` is not entirely necessary, but better have it than not.

Your regex might be looking for matches anywhere in the string, which won't work if the part it's checking is after the `p` in `password`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. What did you mean by anchor the regex?

Comment: @M1Reeder `^` matches the beginning of the string, so that the regex will actually check the whole string for a match, and not anywhere. When it checks anywhere, it will not match at the start, but it can match in the middle at `assword123` because at this point, there can be matches! Does it make sense?

Comment: I would love to, sorry I am a bit new. How do I explicitly mark your answer? NVM I got it. Thanks again!

Comment: @M1Reeder You just did it :)

Answer (score 5):

You really don't need a regex here...

```
if (str.indexOf("password") === -1) {
    // use str
}
```